# Docusign setting existing Pre-fill tool text in template

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am currently working on a project where we are trying to have multiple templates that use pre-fill tool text box with a common name.  Let's say PatientName. The template #1 might have patientname on page 1 and template #2 the patientname is on page 6.  https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields is a good way to create the text field but what if I want to set the field that has already been added to the document.  I'm following the code in the link above but the exist field does not get set.

```
            Text includedOnTemplate = new Text
            {
                TabLabel = "TextName",
                Value = "Patient Name"
            };
            PrefillTabs PFT = new PrefillTabs();
            PFT.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
            PFT.TextTabs.Add(includedOnTemplate);
            Tabs templateTab = new Tabs
            {
                PrefillTabs = PFT
            };
```

Any ideas what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Pre-fill tabs are intended to be filled by the *sender*, not the integration itself.
If you want to have a text field that's pre-populated by your integration, you would want a standard text tab, not a pre-fill.

Comment: It's an automated process from the sender and is intended to show to all signers. And it can be added in the API integration.  The problem is that I need to specify the X and Y coordinates.  I don't want to maintain that for each template.

Comment: Text tabs can be placed via x/y coordinates or anchor tags - there's no need to use a pre-fill for that. If you want the tag to be visible to all signers, assign it to the first recipient, or enable _Sending Settings > When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients_. If you don't want the recipient to be able edit it, be sure to set the `locked` parameter to `true`.

Comment: It's concurrent signings and not sequential.  I've tried what you are suggesting and it's not working as needed for the project I'm doing.  Prefilled is the suggested route according to docusign documentation

Comment: Write Initial Value isn't working?